How to boot from a UDF-formatted USB key?
Not paying enough attention to the target in a partitioning tool, I erased the GPT on the wrong disk (the main SSD device containing boot and OSes). Now I must rebuild this disk.
I already used (Linux) testdisk utility to try and recover GPT. I can access data (and backup it) but I think not all partitions have been discovered because I can't complete boot from this disk.
The disk was a multi-boot one with Windows 10 and a Linux distro. All user data is on another disk and safe. Only the OSes have been damaged.
Booting to Linux is impossible. Booting to W10 starts but I immediately get a blue screen telling me the OS is damaged.
I tried many tweaks to no avail. Consequently, I decided to reinstall everything. I then downloaded on another computer a W10 recovery media (hoping that the product key is stored somewhere in the Gigabyte motherboard hardware). I transferred the .iso image onto a USB key. The key can be read and opened on this other computer.
However, when I plug it into the failing computer, I can't boot from it. The UEFI sees it (as a generic USB device, without indication of key label or OS name) and that is all.
Back on the other computer I discovered it is formatted UDF. Formatting the key FAT32 does not solve the problem because one file is larger than 4GB, which cannot be handled by FAT32.
I read that UEFI is not required to handle UDF (though this is the now-preferred format for DVDs) but is this true? UEFI can boot from CD or DVD where this format is frequently met. Or is this filesystem managed only by the CD/DVD driver? Note that I can't burn DVDs.
Using UDF on a USB flash drive mentions that default UDF block size is 4096 while USB keys expect 512. Could it be the cause of the problem? Should I reformat my UDF key with a 512-blocksize before copying data?
What is my best option to revive my computer?

To spare visitors the pain to follow a lengthy sequence of comments, I post here the "solution" to the problem: contents of the USB key was not correct. A friend of mine reinitialised the key with good data and the boot issue vanished.

For an official Windows 11 .iso image it would be enough to format it as FAT32 and extract all the files.
Make sure that it has an EFI directory with a file EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi. That's what UEFI firmware will expect to find when booting a non-optical disk.

Back on the other computer I discovered it is formatted UDF. Formatting the key FAT32 does not solve the problem because one file is larger than 4GB, which cannot be handled by FAT32.

If it's the Install.wim file, use dism /Split-Image to deal with this problem. If you only have Linux, use wimsplit from the "wimlib" or "imagex" package.
According to MS docs, the regular Windows installer also supports looking for Install.wim on other partitions, so it's possible to have a FAT32 bootable partition and an NTFS secondary partition that only stores Install.wim.
Try downloading a different Windows image; if I remember correctly, the recent "public" .iso releases (downloadable for free from Microsoft.com) had an Install.wim that was already under the FAT32 limit. It depends on which Windows editions are included in it, as well as which drivers (and a "Recovery" image might have lots of stuff added).
Finally, some modern firmwares can actually read NTFS filesystems, so mkfs.ntfs and unpacking the .iso contents into that may also be an option.

I read that UEFI is not required to handle UDF (though this is the now-preferred format for DVDs) but is this true? UEFI can boot from CD or DVD where this format is frequently met.

It doesn't actually boot from UDF in this case – similar to how BIOS boot works with CDs, the firmware instead looks for a special "El Torito boot header" which points to a separate bootable file system image.
Originally CDs were not bootable and you had to boot a PC from a floppy disk that loaded a minimal kernel with CD support and proceeded to load the rest of the OS from the CD. With the "El Torito" format, it's very much the same – the CD filesystem is not booted directly, but rather has an image of a bootable disk embedded adjacent to the ISO9660 or UDF filesystem.
(As a side note, UEFI requires bootable UDF media to follow the "UDF Bridge" format which means they are actually dual UDF/ISO9660 filesystems, and El Torito is actually the procedure for booting from ISO9660 CDs.)
The specification allows a single ISO9660 filesystem to store multiple such images for different platforms, e.g. one for x86 PC and another for PowerPC Macs, and there is also a platform ID defined for "UEFI" in which the image would contain a tiny FAT32-based EFI System Partition. That's what is really being booted when the image is written to a CD or DVD.
AFAIK, Linux "hybrid ISO" images are often prepared so that the MBR or GPT partition table (for HDD/USB boot) has an "EFI System Partition" which references the exact same data as the El Torito boot image (for CD boot).

Using UDF on a USB flash drive mentions that default UDF block size is 4096 while USB keys expect 512. Could it be the cause of the problem? Should I reformat my UDF key with a 512-blocksize before copying data?

It's more about logical sector size than filesystem block size. Nearly all USB disks (and most internal disks) are addressed in terms of 512-byte sectors, while data CDs are addressed in terms of 2048-byte sectors.
Using filesystem block sizes larger than the disk sector size is completely normal, and the difference doesn't matter as long as the filesystem's structures are all defined in absolute values (bytes) rather than being relative to the disk sector size.
But it can result in funny things when an image built for one sector size is written to a disk that uses another. For example, you can actually fit a 34-sector GPT partition table inside the 16-sector reserved area of an ISO9660 filesystem, because the reserved area is actually 16×2048 bytes when the image is read from a CD but the GPT is only 34×512 bytes when it's read from a USB stick.
(For the same reason, the ISO9660 filesystem itself may not be readable when written to a USB stick; its header starts at sector 16, so the image would have it at byte offset 16×2048, but if such an image is written to a 512-byte-sectored USB stick, this byte offset ends up at sector 64 instead – far away from where the firmware is expecting to find it!)

Thanks for the explanation, but how can I create a bootable key from the .iso I downloaded from Microsoft? I formatted my key UDF with bs=512, then cp'ed everything on it. Now, my key is not even detected by UEFI! So what is a practical solution?

Copy its contents to a FAT32 filesystem as you have mentioned in your post, with dism to split the oversized file.

Meanwhile, I recreated the key with dd (without tweaking the filesystem). The key is detected by UEFI (but not its contents). -- I'll try to find a package with wimsplit.

Still no success. I partitioned my key as FAT32 with full contents except install.wim and NTFS with install.wim. FAT32 partition is marked as bootable. Key is detected by UEFI, offering to start on partition 1. But nothing happens and I'm back to device choice. -- Is there any chance of success if I split with wimsplit?

If it doesn't even boot then you're having a different problem – install.wim is only needed when the installation or repair starts, but not involved in merely booting the Windows environment. Does the disk contain an EFI directory with EFI\boot\bootx64.efi? As far as I remember, these steps used to be enough for recent official Win10/Win11 ISO images (download one from MS), but since you mention having downloaded a recovery image from somewhere, not sure how it is built.

When you get obsessed by a problem, you no longer see the obvious. I dropped everything and went to bed. This morning I am relaxed enough to think cleanly. While separating the key into FAT32+NTFS, I messed up the directory structure. Now it boots inside the installer. Let's see how it runs. PS: the recovery media was downloaded from Microsoft site.

I now stumble on "needed driver missing". I suppose it is related to NTFS partition. Also tutorials I found are not very clear about how install.wim should be installed in the NTFS partition (which directory?). Can you suggest "good" links to create the key. Please note I can do that only under Linux. Therefore .bat scripts don't help me.

The relevant Microsoft docs (option A) say that it should be in the root directory. I've never used this method myself; always preferred to split the .wim using wimsplit or DISM instead.

In the worst case, as long as you can boot the WinPE USB environment (and access its CLI with Shift-F10), then you can manually partition; apply the .wim using dism; install the bootloader using bcdboot, and have a working installation that way.

I have rebuilt the USB key with a single 8GB FAT32 partition and used wimsplit. I kept only the SSD in the computer and wiped out the GPT (no partitions declared). I still get the "needed media driver missing" but the dialog does not tell which. Do you think I should unplug the DVD drive or even remove the GPU (running on integrated graphics)?

Removed DVD and GPU: no change.

I don't think I've seen that message before, but most likely it refers to drivers for your SSD – e.g. if you have Intel RST enabled (which hides the standard AHCI or NVMe devices behind a custom controller), Windows might not have drivers for that.

Disabling IRST, fast boot not enabled, has no effect. PC is UEFI-only; can't experiment with legacy mode.
